# How to avoid deletion of class members after assignment?

Tags: c++, linked-list, binary-tree, singly-linked-list

I implemented singly linked list using binary-tree concept to insert elements in the list (tree).
When I copy the values of a list using assignment like that

```
Tree<A> list1, list2;

//Filling list1...

list2 = list1;

//Remove all elements of list1 using the implemented remove method...

print(list2); //throws an error as its elements appear to have been removed as well
```

It seems to also copy the pointers of class members (**m_pLeft** and **m_pRight**) of the tree. Does anyone know why ? and  how can I avoid it?

```
template<typename T>
class Tree {

    class ListElem {
    public:

        ListElem(T t) : m_Elem(t) {}
        ListElem(const ListElem&) = delete;
        ListElem& operator=(const ListElem&) = delete;

        T m_Elem;
        ListElem* m_pLeft = nullptr, * m_pRight = nullptr;
    };

public:
    unsigned size() const {
        return this->length;
    }
    void remove(T t)
    {

        if (this->length > 0) 
        {
            this->m_pHead = remove(this->m_pHead, t);
        }

    }

private:

    ListElem* m_pHead = nullptr;
    unsigned length = 0;
    
};
```

The full code can be found [here](https://codeshare.io/5oR1rM).

Comment: Maybe this answer would help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/9171697

Comment: Probably `m_pLeft` and `m_pRight` aren't being copied in `list2 = list1;`. Rather, both have the same `m_pHead` pointer to the same `ListElem`, so changing that single `ListItem` head object has effects visible from both `Tree<A>` variables. If `Tree<T>` should be copyable, you'll probably want it to implement "deep copy". I think Ðаn is suggesting that using `std::unique_ptr<ListItem>` instead of raw pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Please edit a [mcve] into the question, something we can compile.

Comment: Data types with pointer members very often need non-trivial implementation of special member functions.  Follow the "Rule of Five".

Comment: @aschepler yes but I have to use the normal pointer

Comment: @BenVoigt  I updated the [code](https://codeshare.io/5oR1rM) following _Rule of Five_ can you take a look please?